# How to determine when a map waypoint is reached

Tags: java, android, navigation

I have a navigation program, and if there are 4 waypoints, I would like to highlight on the details list which part you are currently on, and also I could show the distance to the next waypoint and the total distance.

So, you may have:

1. Go right on Main Street, 1.3 miles
2. Go left on Broadway, .5 miles
3. Go left on Concord Blvd, 2 miles

But, how do I determine when a phone starts on a different waypoint.

Comment: Use the Location.distanceTo() function and the [Closest pair of points algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem)

Comment: @Reno - This is what I basically went with after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) you can set several ways for updates on a particular program.  Use [LocationManager.addProximityAlert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) to be alerted if you're in a particular distance to a waypoint. Additionally you can use `Location` classes to get distance for example `waypoint.distanceTo(currentLocation);`.

Comment: Thank you.  This looks like it will be just what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am going with is to use a passive provider, so that if the navigator is being used then my application will still know where the user is.

Then, just keep track of where they were previously and where they are now, and look at the difference in how far they are from the waypoint, and once they get to a certain distance then let them know and change to the new waypoint.

The addProximityAlert made it difficult to know which waypoint to change to and  it didn't work as well as I was hoping, and since I need to know where the user is to update their marker, there was no reason not to just add some calculations at the same time.